# Cropping attributes to only show those inside a layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am currently learning to use ArcMap and I am trying to crop the lines (roads) in the below image to only those inside the state polygon. Is there a way to do this. I have tried via the attribute table, but this is as far as I could get.

[image: Road network]

Comment: Thank you. I had tried this to no avail, but on looking at the error code I have worked out why! You have really helped as I was unsure I was going down the right route. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to [clip the features](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=How%20Clip%20%28Analysis%29%20works). If you don't have a single large state boundary to work with you might [merge all of the counties](http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=ask.answers&q=1565) into one before clipping.

If you are just learning then I would browse through the help file geoprocessing topics. They are informative and you will probably find processes you didn't know exist. I have spent hours in the help files and keep referring to them because they are well written in most cases.

Comment: To compliment this answer you could also use the Intersect tool. Help states _"Computes a geometric intersection of the input features. Features or portions of features which overlap in all layers and/or feature classes will be written to the output feature class."_

Comment: Yea - with intersect the attributes of the state and the attributes of the roads will be combined into one attribute table. Clipping doesn't combine the attribute tables.